# Gitlab-Runner service not working in windows

Tags: windows, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm starting with gitlab CI.

I'm using **Windows 7**. I registred my GitlabRunner, but when I try to install it, I have this issue :

```
←[0;33mWARNING: Since GitLab Runner 10.0 this command is marked as DEPRECATED and will be removed in one of the upcoming releases←[0;m
←[31;1mFATAL: Failed to start gitlab-runner: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.←[0;m
```

Can you help me, please ? thnks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, The service was launched by the Local System user, which does not add the Windows\system32 in the PATH. 
I changed the user who launches the service to %username% of the session and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I can't help. This issue seems to be happening in [Windows and Linux as well](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2767).

I also received the following messages in the terminal:

`Setting up gitlab-runner (10.0.0) ...
GitLab Runner: creating gitlab-runner...
WARNING: Since GitLab Runner 10.0 this command is marked as DEPRECATED and will be removed in one of the upcoming releases
gitlab-runner: Service is not running.
WARNING: Since GitLab Runner 10.0 this command is marked as DEPRECATED and will be removed in one of the upcoming releases
gitlab-ci-multi-runner: Service is not running.
WARNING: Since GitLab Runner 10.0 this command is marked as DEPRECATED and will be removed in one of the upcoming releases
WARNING: Since GitLab Runner 10.0 this command is marked as DEPRECATED and will be removed in one of the upcoming releases`

Comment: thnks for answering, I found the solution :D